# SQL - Sum a row of values based on Dates

Tags: sql, math, sum

I have following type of data

ingredients:

```
Milk
Apple
Rice
...
```

Then its purchased Date

```
26.10.2020
25.10.2020
etc
```

Each item is recorded when its purchased.

I want now to get at the right hand side to see how many times I bought apples, rice & milk.

As now I only see

```
Dates --->    25.10.2020|24.10.2020

Rice             1          NULL
Milk             1           1
Apples           NULL        1
```

My Goal is to see:

```
  Dates --->    25.10.2020|24.10.2020     SUM
    
    Rice             1          NULL       1
    Milk             1           1         2
    Apples           NULL        1         1
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Show the query you used already to pivot the data. Tell us what database you use

Comment: Postgre SQL

select date_trunc ('day', shopping.created_at) as "DATUM" , items.object_name, count ( distinct items.object_name) 
from shopping
RIGHT JOIN items
on shopping.id = items.id
group by 1,2

Comment: Gotta be honest I@m not seeing how that will put columns of daets across the top. Please go here http://dbfiddle.uk and make a representative example table, insert sample data and put your existing query please

Answer (score 0):

[The example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CkT7.png)

Now I want to see at the end to total SUM, as there would be multiple days.